# Google places library in android

Tags: android

Do Autocomplete prediction uses place nearby search inbuild. Places API costing high when using FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest in android.

I am using FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest in android and ios but it is costing Near by places search api, contact data and atmosphere data.